# Packaging ruby script(s) along with gems for end user multi-platform distribution

Tags: ruby, packaging

I created a GUI application with help of two gems. This application contains a few ruby scripts and a folder containing non ruby files. How do I package my application for various platforms? This can be either standalone or installer-like deb or rpm. I checked fpm and omnibus for creating packages, but could not succeed as I do not know how to
include gem and folder/extra files in to a package. To sum it up:

What I have in project directory:

1. A few ruby scripts
2. Files/a folder containing non ruby files
3. Ruby script(s) that use(s) gems (qtbinding and ruby-dbus)
4. My application is also depends on syslinux and other few packages.

What I want:

1. .deb
2. .rpm
3. (any other native distro packages)
4. .exe
5. Standalone packages (if possible)
6. Good writeup on packaging

What I tried:

1. RubyScript2Exe
2. exerb
3. omnibus
4. fpm

What I got:

1. RubyScript2Exe and exerb -->> erro in both the script. Does not run properly. Seems to be obsolete.
2. fpm -->> could not include gem and other files for packaging.
3. omnibus -->> Seems to be suitable but got an error while building

Error raised was:

```
No configuration file `/home/sundar/omnibus-myproject/omnibus.rb', using
defaults
No configuration file `/home/sundar/omnibus-myproject/omnibus.rb', using
defaults
Could not extract version information from `git describe`. Setting
version to 0.0.0
Something went wrong...the Omnibus just ran off the road!

Could not load the Omnibus projects.
```

My target is end users, not developers.  I am not interested in creating a gem for this reason.

Comment: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Ruby?rd=Packaging/Ruby#Applications

Comment: @guido Where does it say about packaging scripts and gems? i have also gone through debian ruby packaging guide as well. https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Ruby/Packaging It seems packaging ruby application is real pain.